# localhost Linux Mint 64bit Babylonjs Chrome Firefox Error "Webgl not supported"

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, localhost, webgl

Имеется Linux Mint 17.2 х86_64. Chrome версии  46.0.2490.80 (в FF то же самое, FireFox версии 38.0). Cвежак.

Работает Apache2, на localhost-e лежит JS проект, в котором подключена библиотека Babylon.js (`src="http://cdn.babylonjs.com/2-2/babylon.js"`), в index.html проекта только инициализация Вавилона, и тут на тебе,

```
Uncaught Error: WebGL not supported @ babylon.js:6(anonymous function) @ localhost/:28
```

Заходим на http://babylonjs-playground.com/#, в другой вкладке того же браузера -

```
BJS - [15:37:19]: Babylon.js engine (v2.3.0-alpha) launched
```

Однако на синем поле в Хроме не отображается ничего, кроме, собственно, синего поля.

В FF на странице Плейграунда даже фигуры прорисованы.

Зато при переходе на тем же FF-ом на localhost/, где инициализационые строки в index.html теге сугубо такие

```
var o = {};
o._canvas = document.getElementById('C');
o._engine = new BABYLON.Engine(o._canvas, true);
```

мы видим ошибку `Error: WebGL not supported babylon.js:6:2101`

Что это? (Что со мной?)

В обоих браузерах все рекомендации по флагам и другим настройкам для разрешения WebGL выполнены.

Куда смотреть дальше?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос оказался в том, что я пытался инициализировать несуществующий canvas, и вопрос не имеет смысла.

Но удалять не стану. Быть может этот "простой ларчик" послужит напоминанием кому-нибудь пересмотреть лишний раз html-часть кода, если ошибка из неестественных.